# What are the differences between android studio and the eclipse version bundled with android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, ide, android-studio

I don't have experience in android development and I'd like to start writing an application.

The [official developer tools page](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html) contains link to two different IDEs. The first contains a bundled ADT version of [Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html).
[Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), the second IDE, is based on IntelliJ.

Apart from these differences I can't get if there is anything that I can do with only one of them (I guess the answer to this question is no) and what's the point of having two distinct *official IDEs*.

What are the differences between the two?

Comment: Android studio is better in my opinion. Incomplete but faster and good designer support.  I am not switching back.

Comment: Here is a detailed explanation on the key differences: https://www.airpair.com/android/android-studio-vs-eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The first contains a bundled ADT version of Eclipse.

This is simply a packaging convenience. You are welcome to obtain Eclipse separately and add Android tooling to it.

> Android Studio, the second IDE, is based on IntelliJ.

At the present time, this is an early-access preview. IMHO, it is not suited for someone who does not have experience in Android application development.

> Apart from these differences I can't get if there is anything that I can do with only one of them

At the present time, Android Studio is an early-access preview, meaning that there are lots of things that it does not have integrated in. Now, by this time next year, and hopefully far sooner, Android Studio will have equivalent or superior integration than does Eclipse with the ADT plugin.

> and what's the point of having two distinct official IDEs.

There are an infinite number of "official" tools. You are welcome to use a plain text editor and tools outside of any IDE, for example.

You are welcome to watch [the Google I|O 2013 video on developer tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lmv1dTnhLH4), where they describe a bit of the rationale behind the development of Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still do not understand what you mean when you say that "There are an infinite number of "official" tools". Can you please explain it?

Comment: @mariosangiorgio: You appear to have some Python experience. You wrote your Python source using vi, or emacs, or Notepad, or BBEdit, or Komodo IDE, or any one of thousands of editors. You ran your Python code using a Python interpreter. Does that make your editor not "official"? Similarly, the Android SDK ships with tools that, along with a Java compiler, let you build Android apps using any of those editors. Those editors, IMHO, are as "official" and are as supported as you find with Eclipse and IDEA. You, of course, are welcome to have whatever definition you want for what is "official".

Comment: I got your point. I was thinking at 'official' IDEs as the ones that Google provides for android development.

Answer (score 8):

**Android Studio vs Eclipse – Main Differences:**

**Build Tools**

> Android Studio utilizes the fast growing Gradle build system. It
>   builds on top of the concepts of Apache Ant and Apache Maven but it
>   also introduces a Groovy DSL (Domain-Specific Language) that allows
>   for scripted builds which opens up many automation possibilities like
>   uploading your beta .apk to TestFlight for testing. Eclipse on the
>   other hand uses Apache Ant as its main build system which a very
>   robust XML based build system that many Java developers may already be
>   familiar with.

**Advanced Code Completion/Refactoring**

> Both IDEs feature the standard Java code auto completion but in the
>   case of Android Studio, Google has baked in deeper support for
>   specific Android code and refactoring. Android Studio can refactor
>   your code in places where it’s just not possible using Eclipse and
>   ADT. In addition, in my opinion IntelliJ’s Java auto completion seems
>   more “intelligent” and predicts better what I want to do so there is
>   definitely an improvement in this area over Eclipse.

**User Interface Design**

> One of the main selling point Google used to market Android Studio
>   when it came out was its completely redesigned user interface design
>   tool. After working with it for some time, it’s clear that the new
>   tool is much better than the old. It literally crashes it. The new
>   interface design too in Android Studio is faster, responds to changes
>   more rapidly and has more customization options that with Eclipse, you
>   had to manually set in the XML.

**Project Organization**

> Both IDEs work differently in an effort to help you manage and
>   organize your projects. If you’ve used Eclipse then you must be
>   familiar with the concept of workspaces. When Eclipse starts, you
>   select the workspace that contains your projects and you can load all
>   project of that workspace in your tree navigation. If you want to
>   switch to a project in a different workspace, then you have to restart
>   the whole IDE. Android Studio treats this situation differently by
>   introducing the concept of modules. Your app could be one module, a
>   library that you just downloaded can be another and the Ad SDK you are
>   currently integrating could be a third. Each of these modules can have
>   their own Gradle build files and declare their own dependencies. To
>   me, Android Studio seems more natural but it takes some time to get
>   used to if you have been using Eclipse for a long time.

**IDE Performance/Stability**

> Eclipse is a purely Java based software, and a big one. In order to
>   run it reliably you need to have more than decent amount of RAM and
>   good CPU power to back it up. Many user who do not strictly meet these
>   criteria are reporting very bad experiences with it. It is not unusual
>   for Eclipse to crash while exporting an apk or having to restart it
>   after using it for a few hours straight. Having said that, Android
>   Studio is still in beta so it comes with its own bugs that crash the
>   IDE every now and then but in the meanwhile, the whole experience
>   feels faster and more robust.

**Conclusion**

> Having used both Android Studio and Eclipse for a while now, I would
>   personally say that Android Studio has the edge over the two. It might
>   be a bit unstable yet and some updates require a complete
>   re-installation of the software but when it eventually comes out of
>   beta, it will blow Eclipse with ADT out of the water. I especially
>   like the stability of the editor and not having to reboot every now
>   and then, the new and improved UI designer and the sexy themes that
>   make Android Studio a real eye candy. What side will you take in the
>   Android Studio vs Eclipse battle?

Answer (score 6):

Besides the numerous points already made, while you can use the ADT tool for other projects outside Android, the Android Studio is purely dedicated to the development of Android apps.Android Studio also allows you to work faster as it gives you intelligent suggestions as you type, freeing you from the shackles of having to go back to your .java or .xml files to look up names of variable or other stuff you can't remember.I just started using Android Studio myself and i can say i am never leaving it.It is particularly good for new programmers.

Comment: ADT Bundle downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html is also purely dedicated to dedicated to the development of Android apps. Both products has their own special features.